# MYSQL - Convertir filas a columnas

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Debo hacer una consulta de 2 tablas donde el contenido de una de ellas -sus filas- debe estar mostrada en columnas.

El resultado que se desea obtener es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado realizandolo con un contador pero no logro que el contador se reinicie cuando cambie el nro de pedido, tambien con una subconsulta y tampoco.

PD: Solo debe mostrar solo las primeras 5 incidencias, así sean 8 o 9 incidencias.

Aquí les puedo dar un Script con los datos necesarios para pruebas:

```
> CREATE TABLE `tmp_guia` (   `sguia_numero_pedido` varchar(15) NOT NULL
> DEFAULT '',   `sguia_hoja_ruta` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
> `satencion_persona` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' ) ENGINE=InnoDB
> DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
> 
> insert tmp_guia values ("N001", "HB001", "JOSE PEREZ"); insert
> tmp_guia values ("N003", "HB003", "JAVIER SOLIS"); insert tmp_guia
> values ("N002", "HB002", "MARIA ROSARIO");
> 
> CREATE TABLE `tmp_guia_incidencia` (   `sguia_numero_pedido`
> varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `sguia_item` char(02) NOT NULL
> DEFAULT ''   `sguia_incidencia` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' )
> ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
> 
> insert tmp_guia_documentos_cliente values ("N001", "01", "FUERA DE
> LUGAR"); insert tmp_guia_documentos_cliente values ("N003", "03",
> "CANCELADO"); insert tmp_guia_documentos_cliente values ("N003", "02",
> "NO HUBO COORDINACION"); insert tmp_guia_documentos_cliente values
> ("N002", "01", "INICIADO"); insert tmp_guia_documentos_cliente values
> ("N003", "01", "INICIADO"); insert tmp_guia_documentos_cliente values
> ("N002", "02", "FINALIZADO");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Qué te parece si, en vez de en diferentes columnas, figurasen todas las incidencias en un único campo separadas por comas?

```
SELECT sguia_numero_pedido,sguia_hoja_ruta,
  satencion_persona,
  GROUP_CONCAT(sguia_incidencia) incidencias
  FROM tmp_guia JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM tmp_guia_incidencia
      WHERE sguia_item<=5
  ) tmp_guia_incidencia 
  USING(sguia_numero_pedido)
  GROUP BY sguia_numero_pedido
  ORDER BY tmp_guia.sguia_numero_pedido,sguia_item;
```

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp_guia` (
  `sguia_numero_pedido` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sguia_hoja_ruta` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `satencion_persona` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT charset = utf8;

INSERT tmp_guia
  VALUES ("N001", "HB001", "JOSE PEREZ");
INSERT tmp_guia
  VALUES ("N003", "HB003", "JAVIER SOLIS");
INSERT tmp_guia
  VALUES ("N002", "HB002", "MARIA ROSARIO");

CREATE TABLE `tmp_guia_incidencia` (
  `sguia_numero_pedido` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sguia_item` char(02) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sguia_incidencia` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT charset = utf8;

INSERT `tmp_guia_incidencia`
  VALUES ("N001", "01", "FUERA DE LUGAR"); 
INSERT `tmp_guia_incidencia`
  VALUES ("N003", "03", "CANCELADO"); 
INSERT `tmp_guia_incidencia`
  VALUES ("N003", "02", "NO HUBO COORDINACION"); 
INSERT `tmp_guia_incidencia`
  VALUES ("N002", "01", "INICIADO");
INSERT `tmp_guia_incidencia`
  VALUES ("N003", "01", "INICIADO"); 
INSERT `tmp_guia_incidencia`
  VALUES ("N002", "02", "FINALIZADO");
```

Obtendría este resultado:

```
+---------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| sguia_numero_pedido | sguia_hoja_ruta | satencion_persona | incidencias                             |
+---------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| N001                | HB001           | JOSE PEREZ        | FUERA DE LUGAR                          |
| N002                | HB002           | MARIA ROSARIO     | FINALIZADO,INICIADO                     |
| N003                | HB003           | JAVIER SOLIS      | INICIADO,NO HUBO COORDINACION,CANCELADO |
+---------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Si necesariamente tiene que ser en campos separados, sería así:

```
SELECT * FROM tmp_guia LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sguia_numero_pedido,sguia_incidencia incidencia_01
      FROM tmp_guia_incidencia
      WHERE sguia_item='01'  
  ) c1 USING(sguia_numero_pedido) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sguia_numero_pedido,sguia_incidencia incidencia_02
      FROM tmp_guia_incidencia
      WHERE sguia_item='02'  
  ) c2 USING(sguia_numero_pedido) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sguia_numero_pedido,sguia_incidencia incidencia_03
      FROM tmp_guia_incidencia
      WHERE sguia_item='03'  
  ) c3 USING(sguia_numero_pedido) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sguia_numero_pedido,sguia_incidencia incidencia_04
      FROM tmp_guia_incidencia
      WHERE sguia_item='04'  
  ) c4 USING(sguia_numero_pedido) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sguia_numero_pedido,sguia_incidencia incidencia_05
      FROM tmp_guia_incidencia
      WHERE sguia_item='05'  
  ) c5 USING(sguia_numero_pedido)
  ORDER BY sguia_numero_pedido;
```

O así:

```
SELECT *,(
    SELECT sguia_incidencia FROM tmp_guia_incidencia WHERE sguia_item='01'
      AND tmp_guia_incidencia.sguia_numero_pedido=tmp_guia.sguia_numero_pedido
  ) incidencia_01,(
    SELECT sguia_incidencia FROM tmp_guia_incidencia WHERE sguia_item='02'
      AND tmp_guia_incidencia.sguia_numero_pedido=tmp_guia.sguia_numero_pedido
  ) incidencia_02,(
    SELECT sguia_incidencia FROM tmp_guia_incidencia WHERE sguia_item='03'
      AND tmp_guia_incidencia.sguia_numero_pedido=tmp_guia.sguia_numero_pedido
  ) incidencia_03,(
    SELECT sguia_incidencia FROM tmp_guia_incidencia WHERE sguia_item='04'
      AND tmp_guia_incidencia.sguia_numero_pedido=tmp_guia.sguia_numero_pedido
  ) incidencia_04,(
    SELECT sguia_incidencia FROM tmp_guia_incidencia WHERE sguia_item='05'
      AND tmp_guia_incidencia.sguia_numero_pedido=tmp_guia.sguia_numero_pedido
  ) incidencia_05
  FROM tmp_guia;
```

Obteniendo:

```
+---------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| sguia_numero_pedido | sguia_hoja_ruta | satencion_persona | incidencia_01  | incidencia_02        | incidencia_03 | incidencia_04 | incidencia_05 |
+---------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| N001                | HB001           | JOSE PEREZ        | FUERA DE LUGAR | NULL                 | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          |
| N002                | HB002           | MARIA ROSARIO     | INICIADO       | FINALIZADO           | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          |
| N003                | HB003           | JAVIER SOLIS      | INICIADO       | NO HUBO COORDINACION | CANCELADO     | NULL          | NULL          |
+---------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```